# Feature detection in jquery : test if browser return nodes of type Text_Node

Tags: jquery

With jQuery.support and without using jQuery.browser how would I know if the browser would return nodes of Type of Text_Node ?

Ex: Would the value of $(this).contents().length be the same in Firefox and IE if there is nodes of type Text_Node ?

Found my response [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301993/jquery-detect-ie6-using-jquery-support-not-jquery-browser):

```
jQuery.support.leadingWhitespace
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> jQuery.support.leadingWhitespace
```

Answer (score 2):

$('td') will always return a jQuery object, not an actual DOM element or node.  jQuery does this in order to standardize behaviour and help alleviate the need for browser-specific handling of different types.

Comment: +1: you never need to know if the type is text_node if you always let jQuery handle the DOM manipulation.

Comment: My question was not well formulated. There is a thread on how to obtain text nodes with Jquery here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery. 
But Firefox will give a different results with $(this).contents().length than IE. So my question persist